# Is it possible to use an answer from a calculation in the same cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to use an answer from a calculation in the same cell?
Eg

Cell A £105

Cell B 0.05 discount

Cell C £105*0.05, ans-£105 = £99.75

I understand I could do it in 2 columns, but wanted to do it all in one calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply expanding the 'ans'  in the formula you already have by using brackets like this:

```
= (A1 * B1) - A1
```

supposing everything is in row 1.

Comment: or `=A1*(B1-1)`

Comment: With either of the above, you're going to get a negative number out at the end.  Just mentioning incase this could be a problem(?)  Otherwise +1 for  both answers

Comment: Cheers @CharlieRB, didn't think I had the rep for that, done now.